# How to convert result from PHP PDO prepared statement to look like DataReader or the result of the fetch?

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions

How to convert result from PHP PDO prepared statement to look like DataReader or the result of the fetch?

I have observed that Firebird PDO requires to use `insert... returning...` as prepared statement to whom the fetch can not be applicable (if fetch is done, then error message `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -502 Cursor is not open` is raised). But the remaining code (Yii framework yii/db/Command/php) expects that the result of `insert... returning...` will be handled at the same way like any `select` satement. So - I would like to use prepared statement and format the result like the result comes from DataReader of fetch? Is that possible?